# Setting up tomcat autostart on Linux?

Tags: linux, tomcat, java, sles

So I have a java web app on tomcat installed on the server. How can I setup auto start for it so that it starts up automatically when the server is restarted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this article here that did it for me.

http://www.sitepoint.com/jsp-quick-start-guide-linux/

Comment: broken link....

Comment: Link updated...

Answer (score 1):

**/etc/init.d/tomcat-wepappname**

```
#!/bin/sh 
### BEGIN INIT INFO 
# Provides:          tomcat-wepappname 
# Required-Start:    $all 
# Required-Stop:     
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5 
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6 
# Short-Description: foo bar 
# Description:       long desc
### END INIT INFO 
# Author: Foo Bar <foo@bar.com> 

. /lib/lsb/init-functions 

# Actions 
case "$1" in 
 start) 
  log_action_begin_msg "Starting tomcat webapp" "tomcat-webappname"
  su - tomcat-webappuser -c "/home/sites/tomcat-webappname/webappname.sh $1" 
  log_end_msg 0 
  ;; 
 stop) 
  su - tomcat-webappuser -c "/home/sites/tomcat-webappname/webappname.sh $1" 
  ;; 
# restart) 
# something else...
#  ;; 
esac

exit 0
```

At least, register the service:

```
update-rc.d activemq defaults
```

Comment: i guess it should be : update-rc.d tomcat-wepappname defaults

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
/sbin/chkconfig tomcat6 on
```

If you have installed the tomcat6 RPM.

Comment: No man I'm using SUSE Enterprise Linux 9 here

Answer (score 0):

One way to start the tomcat on the startup is to run it using cron using the @reboot attribute:

open up a terminal and type :

```
sudo crontab -e
```

at the end of the file enter the command:

```
@reboot /`PATH_TO_WHERE_TOMCAT_INSTALLED`/bin/startup.sh
```

save the file and exit.

The above command will run the command once everytime computer boots up.